# linq include with condition

Tags: linq, include, entity

i have function

```
public Menu Details(int? id)
    {
        return _dataContext.Menu.Include("ChildMenu").FirstOrDefault(m => m.MenuId == id);
    }
```

now i need to add condition to child list ChildMenu something like fieldname=id. how can i do it?

Comment: I'm not really sure what exactly you're trying to do.  Could you clarify the question?

Comment: i have class Menu whith such properties- menuid key, isdeleted bool, parentmenu (reference to parentobject Menu) and childmenu (list of child object list menu). so i need to get parent record with list of child records where isdeleted=false of each child record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return _dataContext.Menu.Include("ChildMenu")
     .Where(m => m.MenuId == id && m.ChildMenu.IsDeleted == false).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Carefully with this solution, it's not correct.

While having an LEFT OUTER JOIN with ON ChildMenu.IsDeleted == 0, we do join only for non-deleted items, but we also keep all menu items, just all ChildMenu properties will be NULL.

The solution above although does a LEFT OUTER JOIN with no condition, but then removes items from the MENU which have Menu.ChildMenu.IsDeleted == 0.

So this is probably not what you wanted!